# What is the class for a jQuery tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I've looked around as this would seem a duplicate sort of question, but it hasn't shown up in my search.

When using jQuery's jQuery(document).tooltip(), what CSS selectors apply to the tooltip?

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not related to class it will apply the custom tooltip on any element having `title` attribute in place. Do you have any specific problem or code to share?

Comment: I want to change the background-color for the tooltip rather than having white on white.

Comment: So looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16522489/447356) is what you need. Didn't you see it?

Comment: @JonathanHayward did my answer work for you or is anything unclear ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the css-class `ui-tooltip` ?

You can also define your own css-class with the following

```
.tooltip({ tooltipClass: "custom-tooltip-styling" })
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-tooltipClass